# Access AuthSession on client after authentication on ServiceStack Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

I'm a little confused with the session documentation, so let's say i'm already send the authentication data from the client side and retrieve the ss-id and ss-pid like this:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://somewhere/theAPI/");
var response = client.Post(new Auth() {UserName = "myuser", Password = "password123"});
var myCookie= client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://somewhere/theAPI"));
```

how I can retrieve the AuthSession information just like the surname, email, etc from the servicestack? do i need it store somewhere else like in memcache server, and retrieve from that?

or I need to build my authentication in the client side? and just use the API to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've already created a custom AuthUserSession, for example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create your own strong-typed Custom AuthUserSession where you can add additional AuthUserSession 
/// fields required for your application. The base class is automatically populated with 
/// User Data as and when they authenticate with your application. 
/// </summary>
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession {
    public string CustomId { get; set; }
}
```

And you've registered your custom AuthUserSession when configuring the AuthFeature plugin, like so:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Register all Authentication methods you want to enable for this web app.            
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
        () => new CustomUserSession(), //Use your own typed Custom UserSession type
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CredentialsAuthProvider(),              //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
            // and any other auth providers you need
        }));
}
```

Then you can expose this data to the client in a service you create.  [SocialBotstrapApi provides access to the current session information on the server like this:](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/496f89b512effa11ea6b2bd493353fb159a517ed/src/SocialBootstrapApi/ServiceInterface/UserAuths.cs)   Use it as a model to create a UserAuth service that returns the information for just the current user.

```
public abstract class AppServiceBase : Service {
    private CustomUserSession userSession;
    protected CustomUserSession UserSession {
        get {
            return base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
        }
    }
}


[Route("/userauths")]
public class UserAuths
{
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}

public class UserAuthsResponse
{
    public UserAuthsResponse()
    {
        this.Users = new List<User>();
        this.UserAuths = new List<UserAuth>();
        this.OAuthProviders = new List<UserOAuthProvider>();
    }
    public CustomUserSession UserSession { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public List<UserAuth> UserAuths { get; set; }

    public List<UserOAuthProvider> OAuthProviders { get; set; }
}

//Implementation. Can be called via any endpoint or format, see: http://servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/
public class UserAuthsService : AppServiceBase
{
    public object Any(UserAuths request)
    {
        var response = new UserAuthsResponse {
            UserSession = base.UserSession,
            Users = Db.Select<User>(),
            UserAuths = Db.Select<UserAuth>(),
            OAuthProviders = Db.Select<UserOAuthProvider>(),
        };

        response.UserAuths.ForEach(x => x.PasswordHash = "[Redacted]");
        response.OAuthProviders.ForEach(x =>
            x.AccessToken = x.AccessTokenSecret = x.RequestTokenSecret = "[Redacted]");
        if (response.UserSession != null)
            response.UserSession.ProviderOAuthAccess.ForEach(x =>
            x.AccessToken = x.AccessTokenSecret = x.RequestTokenSecret = "[Redacted]");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so, after authenticated with CredentialsAuthProvider, then the Client need to send request to retrieve login information from (/userauths) ?

Comment: Exactly.  Session support is only server side, out-of-the-box.